Event from ViewModel to View to cancel and relaunch LaunchedEffect
I am remaking the Simon Says game in Kotin. I try to make a good pattern between my viewModel and my view but here i don't know if there is a better way to execute what i want. So, i need to make my button (light) change color for 700ms when they are clicked. I juste wanted to know if there is a simplest way to do that. My second problem is that if i click on the same button twice when the LaunchedEffect has been launch, i want it to be cancelled an relaunched.
    var greenLight by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var redLight by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var yellowLight by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var blueLight by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    ObserveAsEvents(flow = viewModel.eventChannelFlow) { event ->
        when(event) {
            GameViewModel.UiEvent.TurnGreenLightOn -> { greenLight = true }
            GameViewModel.UiEvent.TurnBlueLightOn -> { redLight = true }
            GameViewModel.UiEvent.TurnRedLightOn -> { yellowLight = true }
            GameViewModel.UiEvent.TurnYellowLightOn -> { blueLight = true }
        }

    }

    LaunchedEffect(greenLight) {
        if (greenLight) {
            delay(700)
            greenLight = false
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(redLight) {
        if (redLight) {
            delay(700)
            redLight = false
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(yellowLight) {
        if (yellowLight) {
            delay(700)
            yellowLight = false
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(blueLight) {
        if (blueLight) {
            delay(700)
            blueLight = false
        }
    }


You can move state and business logic to the ViewModel. Observe the state on the UI and send events to the ViewModel on button clicks. In the ViewModel, start a job that turns the light on, waits for 700 milliseconds, and then turns it off. Before starting the job, check if the previous job is active and cancel it if necessary before starting a new one.
